# I would like get all data between two strings using regex and python

Tags: python, regex

I would like get all data between two strings

I want all text from 'config firewall policy' to 'end'
(From 'Configure Firewall Policy' to the first line starting with 'End'  )

**Sample of initial text:**

```
config firewall policy
    edit 1
        set name "demo"
        set uuid demo
        set srcintf "demo-b-demo"
        set dstintf "demo"
        set srcaddr "demo.demo.demo.110" "host_10.demo.demo.129"
    next
    edit 2
        set name "demo rule"
        set uuid demo-c532-51eb-end-demo
        set srcintf "end-demo-demo"
        set dstintf "demo"
        set srcaddr "demo.40.demo.129" "demo.40.demo.110"
    next
end
config firewall policy
    edit 3
        set name "VIP-demo"
        set uuid demo-d428-end-demo-demo
        set srcintf "demo-b-inside"
        set dstintf "demo"
        set srcaddr "demo.demo.128.demo" "demo.demo.128.demo"
    next
end
```

**Result must be:**

```
edit 1
    set name "demo"
    set uuid demo
    set srcintf "demo-b-demo"
    set dstintf "demo"
    set srcaddr "demo.demo.demo.110" "host_10.demo.demo.129"
next
edit 2
    set name "demo rule"
    set uuid demo-c532-51eb-end-demo
    set srcintf "end-demo-demo"
    set dstintf "demo"
    set srcaddr "demo.40.demo.129" "demo.40.demo.110"
next
```

**I tried something in Python**
result = re.findall('config firewall policy\s([\s\S]*?)end', str(abovetext))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the fact these delimiters are on separate lines.

That means, you can use

```py
re.findall(r'(?m)^config firewall policy\r?\n\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*\nend$', text)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pqlvAa/1).

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - the `re.M` inline flag variant
- `^` - start of a line
- `config firewall policy` - a string of words
- `\r?\n` - CRLF or an LF line break sequence
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\n` - a newline
- `end$` - a line with only `end` text on it.